# Integral morphism of schemes is separated

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I wish to prove the statement in the second paragraph, right after [Definition 28.42.1.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WG), which goes as follows:

"It is clear that integral/finite morphisms are separated and quasi-compact"

As a first step, I notice that since a morphism is finite if and only if it is of finite type and integral. Therefore we reduce to proving the following statement:

An integral morphism is separated and quasi-compact.

I would appreciate help with the proof that an integral morphism is separated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any integral morphism is affine by definition, and any affine morphism is separated. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S5, e.g.